I am trying to Run Build Task in VSC (C code) and I get an error about missing a project or solution file
I am trying to compile my code (written in C), and I get the following error:

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Previous to this (before I did an update to VSC, I had no issue with running my code.
I installed the compiler through MinGW and updated the compilerPath in the JSON file, but the error persists. Re-start also done

Have you opened VSC to the directory containing the executable? It won't work if you've opened to a parent directory, because VSC feels the need to install a bunch of crap to the same directory as the executable before it will work.
